# How to have an asp.net ajax control automatically reference css files

Tags: css, asp.net-ajax, user-controls, webusercontrols

I was wondering if its possible to have an ASP.NET AJAX custom usercontrol 'register' its use of CSS files like it does with JS files.  ?

Eg: Implementing the IScriptControl interface allows for the GetScriptReferences() to be called by the Script Manager, is there a similar thing for CSS files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You could write your own methods to use embedded resources and generate html to write  them to the page.

As a best-practice approach, though, I wouldn't recommend this.  You should have a clear separation of style and markup.  If you want to write a custom control that is dependent on a stylesheet, then I suggest that you provide a default css file along with your control.

**EDIT (to answer questions in the comments)**

You can run this code to add a reference to the CSS file to your page (at runtime).  Note that because you're using the [RegisterClientScriptBlock method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx), you can manage insert duplication.  Here is an excerpt from the link for the method:

> A client script is uniquely identified by its key and its type. Scripts with the same key and type are considered duplicates. Only one script with a given type and key pair can be registered with the page. Attempting to register a script that is already registered does not create a duplicate of the script.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append(@"<link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""");
sb.Append(this.Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), resourceName));
sb.Append(@""" />");

this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyCSS", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thats what i am trying to do.  I have a css file that needs to ship with the control, just like the JS file.  I dont want to manually write out the name of the css file, as its embedded along with the JS file in the assembly.  In addition to that, if i were to say have the control on a page 50 times (like a text box say), it would try to re-reference the css page 50 times?

Comment: If this is what you want to do, then see my modified answer with a code sample.

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats what i'm looking to do.  Thanks!